# Entity relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a symfony 2 project and wondered about the correct relationship of my entities.

I have users who can own many notebooks and a notebook can contain many notes.

A notebook is tied to a user with a userid as a foreign key.

From my user entity I can call get notebooks to get a collection of notebooks tied to instance of a user.

My question is should notes also contain a foreign key of userid so I can call get notes on a user or is this redundant because notebooks are already tied to a user which I can use to get a collection of all notes by call get notes on each notebook a user owns?

Comment: It isn't necessarily redundant if notes of a book can be taken by another user. If notes of a book can only be made by a single user, then you are probably better off just using a query with joins.

Comment: Can a note exist in more then one notebook? Is a notebook a thing or just a grouping mechanism for notes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it should not.  It's a one-to-many between users and notebooks and then between notebooks and notes.  A user owns notebooks. A notebook owns notes.

Comment: So if I wanted to get all the notes which are 'public' for a particular user. Is it better to have a query in the note repository which takes a user id as an argument and then gets all public notes for that user by joining to the notebook and matching the use id, or is it better to have the query in the notebook repository to return all notebooks with just public notes attached?

Comment: Typically when you create a model with `console`, it will make a blank repository class for you too. This is the best place to put all your custom functions for your models. You could put the function to get all notes for a particular user in there. Then you can get the repository and call the function. Check out this link: `http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes`.

Answer (score 0):

no it should not because it's already related indirectly with the notebook so you can call notebook of a user and the notes of that book